# Adjusting Column Widths with expss Package

Tags: r, html-table, formatting, css-tables, expss

I've been using `expss` frequently and find it very useful, however, in some cases I have column values that are long strings which do not fit into the default column widths.

For example, the image below shows a column that needs widening. What `htmlTables()` options in `expss` can be used to widen columns?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several methods to increase width of the first column. Try
one of the following:

```
library(expss)
expss_output_viewer()

data(mtcars)
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      mpg = "Miles/(US) gallon",
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      disp = "Displacement (cu.in.)",
                      hp = "Gross horsepower",
                      drat = "Rear axle ratio",
                      wt = "Weight (1000 lbs)",
                      qsec = "1/4 mile time",
                      vs = "Engine",
                      vs = c("V-engine" = 0,
                             "Straight engine" = 1),
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      gear = "Number of forward gears",
                      carb = "Number of carburetors"
)


# straightforward column width adjustment
calc_cro_cpct(mtcars, list(vs, am), list(total(), vs %nest% am)) %>%
    htmlTable(., css.cell = c("width: 250px", # first column width
                              rep("width: 50px", ncol(.) - 1)) # other columns width
    )

# row labels padding
calc_cro_cpct(mtcars, list(vs, am), list(total(), vs %nest% am)) %>%
    htmlTable(padding.rgroup = paste(rep("&nbsp;", 20), collapse = ""))

# disable row grouping
calc_cro_cpct(mtcars, list(vs, am), list(total(), vs %nest% am)) %>%
    htmlTable(row_groups = FALSE)
```

Arguments  `css.cell`  and `padding.rgroup` are documented  in the
htmlTable package which `expss` use for rendering HTML table representation (see
?htmlTable::htmlTable).